# Reusability in REST services with JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, reusability

I have a simple REST-like service, implemented in [JAX-RS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) to maintain `Foo`'s. It creates foos with `POST foos`, lists foos with `GET foos` and details a given foo with `GET foo/42` (where 42 is the given foo's id).

```
public class FooService {

  @POST
  @Path("/foos")
  public Foo create(Foo foo){
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(foo);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    return foo;
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/foos")
  public List<Foo> get(){
        List<Foo> foos = //more-or-less generic JPA querying-code
        return foos;
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/foos/{id}")
  public Foo get(@PathParam("id") int id){
        Foo foo = //more-or-less generic JPA querying-code
        return foo;
  }
}
```

Now, if I also have a similar service for maintaining `Bar`'s, how am I suppose to elegantly avoid code repetition?

```
public class BarService {

  @POST
  @Path("/bars")
  public Bar create(Bar bar){
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(bar);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    return bar;
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/bars")
  public List<Bar> get(){
        List<Bar> bars = //more-or-less generic JPA querying-code
        return bars;
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/bars/{id}")
  public Bar get(@PathParam("id") int id){
        Bar bar = //more-or-less generic JPA querying-code
        return bar;
  }
}
```

The only difference is the *path* values specified in the `@Path` annotations. Since this value should be static (visible at compile time) it's not possible to create a `AbstracService` class like:

```
public abstract class AbstracService<X> {

  //abstrac static is not possible
  public abstract static final String PATH;

  @POST
  @Path(PATH)
  public X create(X entity){ ... }

  @GET
  @Path(PATH)
  public List<X> get(){ ... }

  @GET
  @Path(PATH + "/{id}")
  public X get(@PathParam("id") int id){ ... }
}


public class FooService extends AbstractService<Foo>{
      //just override the PATH to be "foos"
}    

public class BarService extends AbstractService<Bar>{
      //just override the PATH to be "bars"
}
```

Do I need to override each service method just to adjust the `@Path` and them call `super`s implementation?

The above classes `FooService` and `BarService` are way too similar to keep my reusability-bell silent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty common throughout my resource classes will be this pattern

```
@Path("foo")
public class FoosResource {
    @GET  // get all `Foo` resources
    ...
    @GET 
    @Path("{id}")  // get `Foo` with this id
    ...
    @POST // create new `Foo` in `foo` collection
    ...
    @PUT 
    @Path("{id}")  // Update `Foo` with this id
}
```

You get the idea. The point is that the name of the collection is on the resource class, instead of the resource method level like you have it

```
@Path("foo/{id}")
```

You going to need a `@Path` anyway to make the class a resource class, why not use the most appropriate name for it.

Another thing I might add is something I often do. I add a `Class` field in the abstract class, with a constructor arg that I can pass the `Class` to. Then in the concrete class implementation, I `super(Foo.class)`. This way, JPA has access to the class, which make it easier to work with type querying.

Comment: That's what I was missing.

Answer (score -1):

Well I am sure you could do something like this

```
@POST
@Path("/{foosOrBars}")//will match to any string
public BaseFooBar create(@PathParam("foosOrBars") String type){

if(type.equals("foos")){
//do something with the foo
}else{
//do something different
}

}
```

So you have a base class `BaseFooBar` which you can extend as a `Foo` or a `Bar`.

But you have to be careful, if you have another method on the same service, also just having the same hierarchy level e.g. /foobar. It should have a fixed identifier and not using the curly braces, otherwise your path will not be matched correctly.

Comment: Too bad the base class (``BaseFooBar``) must known all its extension beforehand.